# How to add duplicate data from a button in delphi?

Tags: delphi, listview

I have two forms with TListview for each form (to show the data I just added).
Its okay when I try to add data from form1 and in Listview(form1), its shown. But i also want, if i add data from form1, Listview(form1) and Listview(Form2) automatically added.

Here is my code:

```
procedure TForm1.btnAddClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  data1,data2    : TListItem;
  m1,m2,m3       : String;
  dat            : TForm2;
begin
  m1 := EMom1.Text;
  m2 := EMom2.Text;
  m3 := EMom3.Text;

  //listview form1
  data1 := ListView1.Items.Add;
  data1.Caption := m1;
  data1.SubItems.Add(m2);
  data1.SubItems.Add(m3);

  //listview form2  
  data2 := dat.ListView1.Items.Add; {error on this code}
  data2.Caption := m1;
  data2.SubItems.Add(m2);
  data2.SubItems.Add(m3);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data2 := dat.ListView1.Items.Add;
```

The variable `dat` has not been initialized. I would expect the compiler to warn you of this. I hope you enabled hints and warnings.

You need to supply a valid reference to a `TForm2` instance. I don't know enough about your program to know where you'll get that reference. Presumably you know the answer.

You should also extract the list view item adding code into a method:

```
procedure AddListItem(lv: TListView; s1, s2, s3: string);
```

You can then call this function twice passing the two different list views.

Finally, were you able to switch to using virtual list views you would not need two copies of the data.